# Windows Phone 8 SQLite DATABASE Get all values in a LISTVIEW

Tags: database, windows, sqlite, xaml, windows-phone-8

How can i retrieve value in the list-view from the database which is already created.
    How to connect to that database and copy to local storage. Need help am beginner to
    the windows phone 8.

Comment: Do you know how to add sqlite database to app or you just need how to retrieve data from database?

Comment: yup i know by using isolated storage.. only need to know reading data prom that database.